# php variable not being filled correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have been looking for an explanation for this, but couldn't find one.

I'm using a Mysql database. 
In my table I have a column called unitPrice. It's type: decimal(10,2) - unsigned

Now as for my php page:

```
    $price = mysql_result($rows, $tel, "unitPrice");
    if(is_null($price ) || $price = ""){
           echo " niet ingevuld ";
    }else{
           echo $price ;                                                                             
    }
```

The if-tag is completed perfectly. Which lets me believe the value is correctly stored into the variable when it comes to NULL and empty values.
Now as for the else-tag, it goes wrong. Normally it should collect the value and store it into $price. Like it did with every single other value I collected previously (but stored in the database with other types)
But when I went to check my website page, there was no value!

When I placed:

```
$price = mysql_result($rows, $tel, "unitPrice");
    if(is_null($price) || $price = ""){
           echo " niet ingevuld ";
    }else{
           echo mysql_result($rows, $tel, "unitPrice") ;                                                                             
    }
```

It showed the result correctly.

It wouldn't be a big problem if it wasn't for the fact that I need the variable somewhere else again and don't wish to keep writing the mysql_result phrase over and over again...

Could anyone please explain why it won't work properly with a variable? And perhaps give me a solution as to how to make it work with a variable?

My apologies if this has been answered before. I've looked around for a while, but couldn't find any answers.

Comment: At the risk of being unhelpful, you should be using PDO for new code.  mysql_ functions are deprecated and not supported

Comment: or use MySQLi functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code.

```
if(is_null($EHprijs) || $EHprijs = ""){
```

Will always evaluate to true. You are assigning "" to $EHprijs instead of doing a comparison

Comment: OMG! >.< How stupid. Thanks for picking that error up! That solved it! Will accept this as the answer when the site allows it

Comment: This happens to everyone every once in a while :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the value is stored in a different variable then the one you are checking.
Change `$price` to `$EHprijs`

```
$EHprijs = mysql_result($rows, $tel, "EHprijs");
```

Comment: Oops! Actually it's EHprijs everywhere, but wanted to use $price to make it English. It has nothing to do with this. I'm going to edit my question.